# Ubuntu 15.04 Bluetooth there was a message on blueman Assistant No adapters found lenovo y510p

Tags: bluetooth

Please help me to solve my blue tooth does not work.
thank you.

Details of my configuration:

```
sudo service bluetooth status:

bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sab 2015-09-05 11:22:47 WIB; 1h 27min ago
 Main PID: 729 (bluetoothd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service

dmesg | grep -i bluetooth:

[    8.950013] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    8.950025] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.950028] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.950029] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.950036] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.657887] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   19.660351] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[   30.846062] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   30.846063] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   30.846066] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  440.282884] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  440.282889] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  440.282892] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11


           └─729 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n

Sep 05 11:22:47 farhan bluetoothd[729]: bluetoothd[729]: Failed to init devi...n
Sep 05 11:22:47 farhan bluetoothd[729]: bluetoothd[729]: Failed to init prox...n
Sep 05 11:22:47 farhan bluetoothd[729]: bluetoothd[729]: Failed to init time...n
Sep 05 11:22:47 farhan bluetoothd[729]: bluetoothd[729]: Failed to init aler...n
Sep 05 11:22:47 farhan bluetoothd[729]: bluetoothd[729]: Failed to init ther...n
Sep 05 11:22:47 farhan systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Sep 05 11:22:47 farhan bluetoothd[729]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Sep 05 11:22:47 farhan bluetoothd[729]: Bluetooth Management interface initi...d
Sep 05 11:22:47 farhan bluetoothd[729]: bluetoothd[729]: Failed to init gatt...n
Sep 05 11:22:47 farhan bluetoothd[729]: bluetoothd[729]: Bluetooth Managemen...d
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

sudo lshw -class network:

 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 28:d2:44:3a:b7:92
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:32 memory:d5100000-d513ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 80:56:f2:d6:e4:ed
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.43.73 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:16 memory:d5000000-d5007fff

sudo rfkill list all :

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

sudo lsusb; uname -a; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware:

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 174f:1474 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Linux farhan 3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:16:32 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
bluetooth             491520  12 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

Comment: File a [bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and give them the info they want.  This device actually worked in the 3.13 kernel and this is a regression.  [This info](http://marc.info/?l=linux-bluetooth&m=143210703524841&w=2) was submitted to the kernel team 4 months ago and it was not acted on

Answer (score 0):

I made a dkms deb file with a btusb.c file that is patched so bluetooth will work

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yau4ieg6iv47xo/btusb-dkms_3.0_all.deb
dpkg -i btusb-dkms_3.0_all.deb
wget http://www.gnebehay.com/blog/lenovo-flexpad-bluetooth-debian/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd
sudo cp BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
```

Reboot and post the results from `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` if it doesn't work